# What are the other options we can get from the result of range.find?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, when you do a range.find you can get the result.address. Are there any other options than .address that we can get from the result? I can't find the word to use to search on Google. It would be nice if we can get other info like result.col or something. Additional options don't show in the code window for the result.

Comment: The result of Find() is a Range object (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or Nothing if no hits was located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the result to get the rest. For example, if you use the code below and if you find a match then you can get the rest of the details. See screenshot.

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Err

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Search String
    strSearch = "Sid"

    '~~> Do the Find
    Set aCell = oSht.Cells.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print aCell.Row      '<~~ Give the Row
        Debug.Print aCell.Column   '<~~ Gives the Column
        '~~> AND SO ON
    End If
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Tip**

You might find [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) an interesting read.

Comment: Range.Find() returns a range object. If you use Sid's technique and assign `aCell` the result of the `.Find()` method then you can use it as if it was a Range object - in fact, it is a Range object :) and +1 for Sid for a nice visual explanation

Comment: Thanks Sid, I was able to figure this out after a couple more research but your post explained it even clearer. I don't know how you're able to display those additional menus like aCell.Activate and .AddComment though, I tried it on my code page but it doesn't show a dropdown of additional options.:)

Comment: That is called intellisense. When you define `acell` as range and then tpye `aCell` and put a DOT after that, then you will get that menu :)