# Excel.Application not closed excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read some data from excel file and close it.
but my code not closed it:

```
Function getColumnOfFirstRow(PATH, size) As Long

Dim oApp_Excel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim column As Long
column = 0

Set oApp_Excel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
oApp_Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
oApp_Excel.Visible = True
Set oBook = oApp_Excel.Workbooks.Open(PATH, ReadOnly:=True)

On Error GoTo errhand
column = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=CStr(size)).column


oBook.Close True
oApp_Excel.Quit


Set oBook = Nothing

errhand:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 91
        column = 0
    End Select
getColumnOfFirstRow = column


End Function
```

I think this part of my code must close it:

```
oBook.Close True
oApp_Excel.Quit
```

Comment: No No. You are doing this incorrectly. When there is an error, it will directly go to errhand and not quit excel. I would recommend going through 2 links **1.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806190/vb6-does-not-terminate-excel-process See here how I'm creating, and disposing the object. **2.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640 Here I have talked about error handling. You can ignore the rest. So you should be quitting and disposing the objects in `Letscontinue:` part of Error handling.

Comment: And a 3rd link.. You should always handle the result of `.Find`. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864988/what-are-the-other-options-we-can-get-from-the-result-of-range-find

Comment: Also where is the function `getColumnOfFirstRow`. Is this in Excel? Word?, VB6? Where?

Answer (score 1):

### Using a New Instance of Excel

- It looks like overkill to open and close Excel and a workbook to just retrieve a number but let's say we're practicing handling objects and error handling.

```vb
Function GetSizeColumn(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Size As Double) As Long

    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True ' out-comment when done testing
    
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path, True, True)
    
    Dim SizeColumn As Long
    SizeColumn = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(CStr(Size)).Column
    ' You can avoid the expected error as you have learned in your newer post. 
    ' In this case, if the error occurs, the function will end up with 
    ' its initial value 0 since its result is declared 'As Long'
    ' i.e. the following line will never be executed.
    
    GetSizeColumn = SizeColumn

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close False
        If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then xlApp.Quit
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function    
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. **100% working code** about creating the excel. In this code, excel converts recordset in excel successfully. After that close the excel successfully. No error.

> Also, **check with the Task manager and close any excel file open in the process.**

```
Public Sub ConvertRecordSetToExcelFull(Rs As Recordset, _
                                   FileNameWithPath As String, _
                                   SheetName As String, _
                                   Rangename As String)

On Error GoTo Error1

Dim ExlFile As Object, Book As Object, Sheet As Object, K As Long, J As Long

Set ExlFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Book = ExlFile.Workbooks.Add
Set Sheet = Book.Worksheets(1)
ExlFile.DisplayAlerts = False
K = 1

For J = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheet.Cells(K, J + 1) = UCase(Rs.Fields(J).Name)
Next
K = K + 1

If Rs.RecordCount >= 1 Then

    'Call RecCount(rs)
    Do While Rs.EOF <> True

        For J = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
            Sheet.Cells(K, J + 1) = Rs.Fields(J)
        Next
        K = K + 1
        Rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End If

Book.Worksheets(1).Name = SheetName
Book.SaveAs FileNameWithPath
ExlFile.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
ExlFile.Quit
Set Sheet = Nothing
Set ExlFile = Nothing
Screen.MousePointer = vbNormal
Exit Sub
Error1:
MsgBox Err.Description
Err.Clear
End Sub
```